# is this an invalid use of pytest.mark.django_db?

Tags: python, django, pytest

For this example everything in the UserProfile model is optional except for the user foreign key to the user model

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def create_userprofile_list():
    full_permissions_user, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="admin_testuser",
        email="admin_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=True,
        is_staff=True,
    )
    staff_permissions_user, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="staff_testuser",
        email="staff_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=False,
        is_staff=True,
    )
    user_permissions, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="normal_testuser",
        email="normal_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=False,
        is_staff=False,
    )
    user_list = [full_permissions_user,
                 staff_permissions_user,
                 user_permissions]
    return [UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0] for user in user_list]

userprofile_list = create_userprofile_list()
```

I would use the userprofile_list in other tests but I can't get this to work with the test database.

the error is as follows:

```
userprofile/tests/test_userprofiles.py:None (userprofile/tests/test_userprofiles.py)
userprofile/tests/test_userprofiles.py:39: in <module>
    userprofile_list = create_userprofile_list()
userprofile/tests/test_userprofiles.py:15: in create_userprofile_list
    full_permissions_user, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py:85: in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:573: in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False

...

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py:26: in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:259: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:235: in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
E   RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

As you can tell I'm going to be running website tests with these users.  Is this a good way to do this? and is this a way to use the pytest.mark.django_db decorator well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `fixture` and use the `django_db` mark on the tests that use it.

```
@pytest.fixture
def userprofile_list():
    full_permissions_user, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="admin_testuser",
        email="admin_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=True,
        is_staff=True,
    )
    staff_permissions_user, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="staff_testuser",
        email="staff_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=False,
        is_staff=True,
    )
    user_permissions, _ = get_user_model().objects.get_or_create(
        username="normal_testuser",
        email="normal_testuser@user.com",
        is_superuser=False,
        is_staff=False,
    )
    user_list = [full_permissions_user,
                 staff_permissions_user,
                 user_permissions]
    return [UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0] for user in user_list]

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_something(userprofile_list):
    ...
```

Comment: The fixture can also use the `django_db` fixture as a dependency, to avoid the mark.

Comment: I changed all the logic from class based to functional.  I wasn't able to use it in the @pytest.mark.parameterize() but I brought all the parameterize logic within the function and it worked!!!